# Perform checks on a nested enum

Tags: rust, enums

I have an enum which is defined as follows:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    X(u32),
    Y(Vec<MyEnum>),
    Z(Vec<MyEnum>),
}
```

As you can see, the enum is nested and can have other enums of its type inside of it. I'm trying to perform a simple check: I want to check if any of the `u32`s is greater than 5.

I have thought about using recursion here as this seems like an inherently recursive problem but from my searches it was clear that rust doesn't support recursion or that it is not recommended that it is used. How would I go about solving this problem and performing the check?

Comment: Can you share the sources that made you believe this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a method over your `Enum`, and recursively call it:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    X(u32),
    Y(Vec<MyEnum>),
    Z(Vec<MyEnum>),
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn greater_than(&self, x: u32) -> bool {
        match self {
            Self::X(v) => v > &x,
            Self::Y(v) | Self::Z(v) => v.iter().any(|y| y.greater_than(x)),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa11f0c88d1dcf823022e75d3758c769)

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly ok to use recursion in Rust, there is no particular problem about it.

In your case, you could write your check like this:

```
fn my_check(en: &MyEnum) -> bool {
    match en {
        MyEnum::X(n) => *n > 5,
        MyEnum::Y(v) | MyEnum::Z(v) => v.iter().any(my_check),
    }
}
```